# Call custom compiled program from matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this custom compile program in linux. I want to call this program from matlab. How can I do it? system('myprogram') command doesn't seem to find it

Comment: Have you tried [this approach](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The `system` matlab function execute a function of the operating system and therefore looks in the system PATH to find the function to execute.

Then, if you want to execute `myprogram` it must be in your path or you must specify the full path to it. For example if `myprogram` is in your current matlab folder you can use:

> system([pwd, '/', 'HamiltonJacobi']);